# Finding duplicate rows in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.1

I have a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE xyz (
    id text,
    profile_name text,
    cret_dt timestamp,
    cret_id text,
PRIMARY KEY(id, profile));
```

It also has some data.

Now, when I run this query:

```
select id  from xyz ;
```

It returns 165 rows

Again, when I run this query:

```
select distinct id  from xyz ;
```

It returns 162 rows.

Is there any way to find out the duplicate 3 rows?

Comment: @Gomes, I don't see how this should work. There is no such thing as a `GROUP BY` clause in CQL. Using count(*) in a query yields a single row with the number of rows in the result set.

Comment: @ralf is right, basically get all the records in client and for a particular key if the second cluster column count is more than 1 then that is the duplicate  row. Again if you want to avoid having duplicate key, your partiion key shoudld have that column like 
CREATE TABLE xyz (
    id text,
    profile_name text,
    cret_dt timestamp,
    cret_id text,
PRIMARY KEY((id, profile))
);